# How to find a duplicate of a list that repeats three times in a row

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Given a list of duplicate numbers, how to find a number that repeats three times in a row. For example:

```
l1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]
```

I want to print element number 3 as it appears three times in a row.

I have tried using `Counter`, which converts this to dict, but not sure how to just print the key that as the max count value.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will correct it right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
L = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]

res = [i for i, j, k in zip(L, L[1:], L[2:]) if i == j == k]  # [3]
```

Generalised for an arbitrary number of repeats, you can use list slicing:

```
n = 3
res = [L[idx] for idx in range(len(L)-n) if len(set(L[idx: idx+n])) == 1]  # [3]
```

Comment: Thanks jpp. If three is variable, what would be the logic in that case. In other words if the task is to identify n duplicate numbers in a row, and print the value of  duplicate number.

Comment: Thanks a lot jpp. It works. I have learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Easy. That should help:

```
d={i:L.count(i) for i in L if L.count(i)>2}
```

This return a dict with the number that are repeated more than2 times.In your case:

```
{3: 3}
```

Comment: Using collection.Counter is better - it touches each value of the list exactly once to build the dictionary that holds all counts. You touch each element of your list len(L) times giving this a N*N complexity - for big dictionaries this is a huge difference. If you have a list with lots of duplicates [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] you still touch 11*11 times - and overwrite the same dictionary key over and over again with the identical count.

Comment: Yes. I also  believe performnce wise its slightly better but then I would still to go for another line to find the keys with values greater than 2 when I can do the whole in one go. Will  go through that again  anyway thanks. @PatrickArtner

Comment: Maybe I've misinterpreted the question, but how does this deal with `repeats three times in a row`? Number of *consecutive* items is lost with `list.count`.

Comment: @lax123 my codde  does print that are counted over 3 times. Run the code and let me know